# getAttribute of session object returns non-null object instead of null object in a JSP page in Tomcat environment

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, getattribute

I am having a problem with `getAttribute()` of session object of JSP in Tomcat environment.

When Connect button is clicked from an initial jsp page, login.jsp , a connect.jsp page (connection page) is invoked to get a database connection object and the object is stored as an attribute in a session object. When user clicks Disconnect button from login page, another page, disconnect.jsp (disconnect page), is invoked, `getAttribute()` is called to get connection object, and `setAttribute()` is called to set the connection object to null. When checked value of the connection object using `getAttribute()`, its value is null as expected in the disconnect page. This is as expected.

After disconnecting, when Connect button is clicked on login page to connect to a database once again, the connection page finds that the connection object retrieved using `getAttribute()` to be a non-null object instead of a null object. This is the problem. Why `getAttribute()` returns a non-null object even though it was already set to null in the disconnect page ?

Once in probably 10 times the code works as expected! But most of the time it fails.

Here is the actual code for reproducing the problem:

### login page:

```
   /* When connection page is invoked 2nd time after disconnecting an 
    * existing connection, the connection page returns saying connection 
    * already exists! - this is not what I expect.
    *
    * The page invoke connection page if user clicks a connect button.
    * It invokes disconnect page if user clicks a disconnect button.
    */


<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="login_form">

<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Connect"  ONCLICK="react_connect(this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Disconnect" ONCLICK="react_disconnect(this.form)">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function react_connect(form)
{
    form.action = "connect.jsp";
    form.submit();  
}

function react_disconnect(form)
{
    form.action = "disconnect.jsp";
    form.submit();  
}
</SCRIPT>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

### connection page:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>  
<FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="conn_form">

<% 
    HttpSession theSession = request.getSession(true); 
    String CONN_OBJ_NAME = "connobj";
    // Use a string object instead of actual database connection object for
    // simulating the problem.
    String CONN_OBJ_VALUE = "dummy conn obj"; 

    String conn = (String)theSession.getAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME); 
    if (conn == null) { 
        theSession.setAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME, CONN_OBJ_VALUE); 
    out.print("After connect: connobj=["+
        theSession.getAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME).toString()+
        "], sessionid="+theSession.getId());
    } else { 
        out.print("Already connected. connobj=["+
            theSession.getAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME).toString()+"], sessionid="+
            theSession.getId());
    }
%>   

<BR><BR><BR>

<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Back to Main page"  ONCLICK="goback(this.form)">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function goback(form)
{
    form.action = "login.jsp";
    form.submit();  
}
</SCRIPT>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

### disconnect page:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="POST" NAME="disconn_form">
<% 
    HttpSession theSession = request.getSession(true); 
    String CONN_OBJ_NAME = "connobj";
    String conn =  (String)theSession.getAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME); 
    if (conn == null) { 
        out.print("Not connected to database.");
    } else {    
        out.print("Before Disconnecting: connobj=[" +
                theSession.getAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME).toString() + 
                "], sessionid="+theSession.getId());

    // set connection object to null in the session.
    theSession.setAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME, null); 

    out.print("<BR>After setting to null, connobj =[" + 
            theSession.getAttribute(CONN_OBJ_NAME)+"], sessionid="+
            theSession.getId());

    theSession.invalidate();
    }
%>
<BR><BR><BR>

<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Back to Main page"  ONCLICK="goback(this.form)">

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function goback(form)
{
    form.action = "login.jsp";
    form.submit();  
}
</SCRIPT>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

When You invoked `getSession` using `boolean` as 'true `request.getSession(true);`, It creates new Session if not found.

First You should get session using `getSession(false)` when disconnecting.
Second, Use `session.invalidate();` - It invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.

Quoting `getSession(boolean create)` from [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

> Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if
>   there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.
>
> If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this
>   method returns null.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but not successful. I will update my post with simple jsp scripts for reproducing the problem.

Comment: The revised code I have posted fails on MS Internet Explorer 9.0 but I have just now found that it  works perfectly alright with Google Chrome browser!

Comment: @user2178786: You should accept the answer if it was helpful. It would also be good for your profile.

Comment: Though your suggested changes did not resolve the problem I have with Internet Explorer, I believe the changes  are appropriate for my application and I will use them. Thank you and I appreciate your effort and suggestions.